# Address with spaces?

Tags: batch-file

```
tree C:\My files >> pathtree.txt
```

It does not seem to work. What I expected to see is a tree of my files, but it outputs `Too many parameters - files`. I think it is because of the space, but I don't know how to fix it. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use quotes.

```
tree "C:\My files" >> pathtree.txt
```